# Prove using induction over the positive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove using induction that the sum of the first step $n$ positive even integers is $n(n+1)$. In other words, prove using induction that $2 + 4 + 6 + … + 2n = n(n+1)$.

So, for my base case I have: the statement is true for $n=2$ as the sum of the first positive integer is $1(1+1) = 2$.

I don't know if this is right, and I am lost on what to do for the inductive step.

Comment: Hint: suppose the formula holds for all $n \leq k$. What happens when $n = k+1?$

Comment: n will be equal to k

Comment: "I am lost on what to do for the inductive step" : Were there previous problems, worked examples, or theorems, involving induction, that you were exposed to, prior to being assigned this problem?  If so, I suggest that you regard these as the tools that the problem composer intends for you to use, to solve the problem.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Your base case is for $n = 1$.  Notice that you found that the sum of the first one positive even integers is $2 = 1(1 + 1) = n(n + 1)$, so $n = 1$.  Proving that the statement $2 + 4 + 6 + \ldots + 2n = n(n + 1)$ for $n = 1$ allows you to assume that the statement holds for some positive integer $m$.  Hence, $2 + 4 + 6 + \ldots + 2m = m(m + 1)$.   This is your induction hypothesis, which you are supposed to use to prove that the statement $2 + 4 + 6 + \ldots + 2m + 2(m + 1) = (m + 1)[(m + 1) + 1]$ also holds.